# JavaFX EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION

Tags: java, javafx, jvm, access-violation, directx-11

I have a problem with JavaFX desktop application, specifically with 3d rendering functionalities.
Every time I try to build and launch JavaFX application, JVM crshes and I get error similiar to following one:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000000000000, pid=8440, tid=9008
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_51-b13) (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.51-b03 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  0x0000000000000000
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# D:\apps\desktop\hs_err_pid8440.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

Entire log: http://pastebin.com/FC6NfVjF

I tried different java version (1.7_51, 1.7_60, as well as 1.8_5), I tried updating graphic card drivers.
Some project does launch, but as soon as I want to display some 'more complicated' effects (i.e. hovering a button), I get the same exception.

Judging from the stacktrace, I believe it has something to do with directX.

```
j  com.sun.prism.d3d.D3DVertexBuffer.nDrawIndexedQuads(J[F[BI)I+0
j  com.sun.prism.d3d.D3DVertexBuffer.drawQuads(I)V+13
j  com.sun.prism.impl.VertexBuffer.flush()V+12
```

I'm working on machine with Windows 8.1 and DirectX 11. Probably it won't help, but here I'm also pasting DirectX Diagnostic Tool log:
http://pastebin.com/giN4AFv4

Thanks for any input.

Comment: You should try to create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). With just the logs it's very unlikely that someone will be able to help you.

Comment: What I can find from the crash log is that the applicated has crashed inside `C:\Windows\system32\igdumdim64.dll` library (a part of Intel HD Graphics Driver) at offset 0xe5fe9. I can't name the exact function without having this particular library, but this would hardly help anyway. There is a Windows-specific Java flag `-XX:+CreateMinidumpOnCrash` that helps to produce a more meaningful crash dump for analysis.

Comment: Ok, thanks to **apangin** I found a solution.

It turned out that acer put some wrong Intel HD drivers, that are not entirely compatible with my HD4400. 
All I had to do was to remove the old HD drivers and install latest version specifically for my CPU downloaded from Intel site. **apangin** - you can answer it here, I will vote for that.

**@Kyllopardiun** - what would be MCV example here ? there weren't any code examples I could paste - everthing was in the logs.

Comment: @ember I am glad that you've solved the problem. I've copied my comment as an answer with a brief explanation how to read the crash log.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The crash has happened inside `C:\Windows\system32\igdumdim64.dll` at offset `0xe5fe9`.
This library is a part of Intel HD Graphics Driver.

Here is a quick tip how to find this from the crash log.

```
# Problematic frame:
# C  0x0000000000000000
```

Zero instruction pointer means there was an indirect call, and the target address happened to be `NULL`. The return address for this call is likely to be on the top of stack.

```
Top of Stack: (sp=0x000000000ef4d398)
0x000000000ef4d398:   00007ffb308b5fe9 000000000e979800
```

`00007ffb308b5fe9` is the saved return address. Let's find the range it belongs to.

```
Dynamic libraries:
...
0x00007ffb307d0000 - 0x00007ffb31019000      C:\Windows\system32\igdumdim64.dll
```

Find the offset in the library by subtracting the base address:
0x00007ffb308b5fe9 - 0x00007ffb307d0000  = 0xe5fe9

Next, having the dll in hand, we can disassemble it and figure out the exact function at the given offset.

*P.S.*
There is also a Windows-specific Java flag `-XX:+CreateMinidumpOnCrash` that helps to produce a more meaningful crash dump for analysis.